# Why does using "and" between two lists give me the second list (as opposed to an error)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I encountered a bug in some code. The (incorrect) line was similar to:

```
[x for x in range(3, 6) and range(0, 10)] 
print x

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

(the correct way of writing this statement is not part of the question)

Wondering what `someList and someOtherList` does, I experimented. It seems to only ever set the result to the last parameter passed:

```
x = range(0,3)   # [0, 1, 2]
y = range(3, 10) # [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
z = range(4, 8)  # [4, 5, 6, 7]

print x and y       # [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print y and x       # [0, 1, 2]
print z and y and x # [0, 1, 2]
```

I would assume that this is an unintentional consequence of being able to write something that *is* useful, but I'm not really seeing how the semantics of the "and" operator are being applied here.

From experience, python won't apply operators to things that don't support those operators (i.e. it spits out a TypeError), so I'd *expect* an error for and-ing something that should never be and-ed. The fact I don't get an error is telling me that I'm missing... something.

**What am I missing? Why is `list and list` an allowed operation?** And is there anything "useful" that can be done with this behaviour?

Comment: that question is about booleans but the answer applies regardless of the types

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns

Comment: I do think the linked question could mention that the problem isn't just boolean lists (it's any list), but I'm not really adding much here. Happy to close as duplicate.

Comment: the answer mentions it *Their contents don't play a role here.*

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns; I saw that the *answer* mentions that (hence happy to close as dupe), but that the *question* might not get people to the right place (example: I didn't see that question when I was searching about my non-boolean lists :-) ).

Comment: OK well I googled "python and operator list" and it was the first hit

Answer (score 2):

The `and` operator checks the *truthiness* of the first operand. If the truthiness is `False`, then the first argument is returned, otherwise the second.

So if both `range(..)`s contain *elements*, the *last* operand is returned. So your expression:

```
[x for x in range(3, 6) and range(0, 10)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[x for x in range(0, 10)]
```

You can however use an `if` to filter:

```
[x for x in range(3, 6) if x in range(0, 10)]
```

In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) `range(..)` however *constructs a list*, making it not terribly efficient. Since we know that `x` is an `int`, we can do the bounds check like:

```
[x for x in range(3, 6) if 0 <= x < 10]
```

Of course in this case the check is *useless* since every element in `range(3,6)` is in the range of `range(0,10)`.

Comment: Similarly (and generally more useful) is using the `or` operator on lists to return the first list that is non-empty.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: yes indeed. Since `or` returns the first element with `True` truthness.